# Update All values from Temporary Table is not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a simple Products table,

**Products**

```
ID Name Price
-----------
1  ABC  12
```

Now I have a temporary table which is trying update `Products` table.

```
DECLARE @TempProducts TABLE (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(20),
    Price varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO @TempProducts
    VALUES (1, 'p1', NULL), (1, NULL, 123)

UPDATE [dbo].[Products]
SET Name = ISNULL(t.Name, P.Name),
    Price = ISNULL(t.Price, P.Price)
FROM [dbo].[Products] P
INNER JOIN @TempProducts t
    ON (P.ID = CAST(t.ID AS int))
```

But only the first row of the temporary table is updated in products table. Note this is huge query simplified here. Please don't suggest cursor

Comment: This is the *expected behavior* for your UPDATE statement. SQL Server doesn't knows what row from `@TempProducts` should pick up for UPDATE. It will select just one row from those two rows.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, is there is a way to tell SQL server please select both rows. Means run update 2 times

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, your solution? where?

Comment: Reload/refresh current web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TempProducts TABLE (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(20),
    Price varchar(20),
    ImportID INT UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO @TempProducts VALUES (1, 'p1', NULL, 101), (1, NULL, 123,102),(1, 'abc', 1, 103),(1, NULL, 11, 104);

UPDATE [dbo].[Products]
SET Name = ISNULL(t.LastNotNullName, P.Name),
    Price = ISNULL(t.LastNotNullPrice, P.Price)
FROM [dbo].[Products] P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  y.ID,
            MAX(CASE WHEN y.RowNumName=1 THEn y.Name END) AS LastNotNullName,
            MAX(CASE WHEN y.RowNumPrice=1 THEn y.Price END) AS LastNotNullPrice
    FROM (
        SELECT  x.ID, x.Name, x.Price, x.ImportID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN x.Name IS NOT NULL THEN x.ImportID END DESC) AS RowNumName,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN x.Price IS NOT NULL THEN x.ImportID END DESC) AS RowNumPrice
        FROM    @TempProducts x
    ) y
    GROUP BY y.ID
) t ON (P.ID = t.ID) -- There is not need for CAST because @TempProducts.ID is INT
```

Comment: Thanks. It will only works if the values are null. If multiple values are there I want to take last one. Means Last without null wins

Comment: @user960567: The last in what order ? Show me an example.

Comment: INSERT INTO @TempProducts
    VALUES (1, 'p1', NULL), (1, NULL, 123),(1, 'abc', 1) Now I need the table should take 'abc' and 1

Comment: @user960567: As I have said: how SQL Server knows what is the last row/value ? I need a unique `ID` column or some date/time column.\

Comment: Actually I have a unique ID called ImportID in @TempProducts which I haven't shown here.

Comment: @user960567: I updated my answer. This solution will selected allways the last row (by `ImportID`) for every `ID` from `@TempProducts`.

Comment: Thanks. Is this works for no null rows as well? Means I need to ignore the NULL. Means if Name is NULL select the previous, if previous is null select previous. This is the biggest issue I am facing

Comment: @user960567: See Edit 2.

Comment: @user960567: I would use an %int/numeric/[small]money data type for column `Price`.

Comment: It still not working on (1, 'p1', NULL, 101), (1, NULL, 123,102),(1, '1Name', NULL, 12),(1, NULL, NULl, 104),(1, NULL, NULl, 105). But that was enough for me to understand my place to go

Comment: @user960567: Using above values `(...) t` derived table (subquery) returns `1 p1 123`. These are the "Last without null" values for `Name` and `Price` columns. Maybe you get diff. results because my `ImportID` column is an `INT` column and yours is an `[VAR]CHAR`column ?